# Block timezone conversion in Mysql: compare the orginal time or date value(which the user gave) to database values

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I have a date field type and a time field type in my table. The table has some row: with time field that has values like 15:00:00 and 16:00:00; I chose time type knowing that it doesn't get infected by the timezone.

Now my problem is the mysql client(user) timezone is UTC+3 so when the user wants to select where time is 18:00:00 the result concerns where time values are 15:00:00 (meaning the value given by the user is being converted to UTC; 18:00:00=15:00:00). But that's not what I want.

What I want is if the user gives 18:00:00 it should be considered as UTC values so that 18:00:00 only select rows where time is save 18:00:00 not 15:00:00. I try to use `select donnees.* from donnees where timefield=CONVERT_TZ(:ptime,'UTC','Africa/Nairobi');` but it is not working and it is giving null value.

I am really confused. How can I compare correctly that?

Answer (score 1):

Extend 'on afterOpen' event of db component.

In config/main.php, specify 'db' component such as:

```
'db' => [
     'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
     'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db_name',
     'username' => 'db_username',
     'password' => 'db_password',
     'charset' => 'utf8',

     'on afterOpen' => function($event) {
            $event->sender->createCommand("SET time_zone = '+00:00'")->execute();
     }              
],
```

Comment: But this will be effective for all query

Comment: Exactly. Otherwise you can send "SET time_zone='+00:00'" to database when you need.